# how to make the query process faster?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

In my app in one activity I make queries from 3 tables present in database which returns 1600 rows, and then i put the row values in Vector(just like ArrayList) of hashmap, to populate a listview. It takes more than 1 minute to complete the process. I want to do it faster. is this possible?

Here's my code...

```
   pd = new ProgressDialog(ListViewActivity.this);
   pd.setTitle("Please wait...");
   pd.setMessage("Loading Data");
   pd.setProgressStyle(pd.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
   pd.setCancelable(false);
   pd.setProgress(0);
   pd.show();

 handler = new Handler(getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    Vector<HashMap<String, String>> saudaList = (Vector<HashMap<String, String>>) msg.obj;
                    String[] from = {"date","sname","bname","contrno","item","quantity","rate"};
                    int[] to = {R.id.textViewSRdate,R.id.textViewSRSname,R.id.textViewSRBname,R.id.textViewSRcontrNo,R.id.textViewSRitem,R.id.textViewSRquantity,R.id.textViewSRrate};
                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), saudaList,R.layout.sauda_row, from, to);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return false;
                }
            });

  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         if (saudaList.size()==0) {
            getAllSaudaEntry();
         }
         Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
         msg.obj = saudaList;
         msg.sendToTarget();
     }
  });
  t.start();

  registerForContextMenu(listView);
}

public void getAllSaudaEntry(){
        db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery;
        String cnumber = (String) b.get("key_cnumber");
        String dateto = (String) b.get("key_dateto");
        String datefrom = (String) b.get("key_datefrom");
        String item = (String) b.get("key_item");
        String buyname = (String) b.get("key_buyname");
        String sellname = (String) b.get("key_sellname");

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
        String[] columns = {dbh.SM_DATE,dbh.SM_CONTRNO,dbh.SM_SELVOU,dbh.SM_BUYVOU,dbh.SM_ITEMVOU,dbh.SM_QUANTITY,dbh.SM_RATE};
        Cursor c = db.query(dbh.TABLE_SAUDAMST, columns, null, null, null, null, null,"100");
        nRows = c.getCount();
        pd.setMax(nRows);
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("date", ""+df.format(new java.util.Date(Long.valueOf(c.getString(0)))));
            map.put("quantity", ""+(int)Float.parseFloat(c.getString(5)));
            map.put("contrno", ""+c.getString(1));
            map.put("rate", ""+(int)Float.parseFloat(c.getString(6)));
            Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+dbh.AM_Name+" FROM "+dbh.TABLE_ACCMST+" WHERE "+dbh.AM_Vou+" = ?", new String[] {c.getString(2)});
            if (c1.getCount()>0) {
                c1.moveToFirst();
                map.put("sname", "" + c1.getString(0));
                c1.close();
            }
            Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+dbh.AM_Name+" FROM "+dbh.TABLE_ACCMST+" WHERE "+dbh.AM_Vou+" = ?", new String[] {c.getString(3)});
            if (c2.getCount()>0) {
                c2.moveToFirst();
                map.put("bname", "" + c2.getString(0));
                c2.close();
            }
            Cursor c3 = db.query(dbh.TABLE_ITEMMASTER, null, dbh.IM_VOU+"=?", new String[]{c.getString(4)}, null, null, null);
            if (c3.getCount()>0) {
                c3.moveToFirst();
                map.put("item", "" + c3.getString(1));
                c3.close();
            }
            saudaList.add(map);
            progress = (saudaList.size());
            pdHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pd.setProgress(progress);
                }
            });

        }
        pd.dismiss();
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Multiple threads will *not* make reading from SQLite faster.

Answer (score 1):

1600 rows X 7 values is a huge amount of data. First of all, you could try putting logs around the query code with the timestamp, that way you will be able to optimize the code that takes the longer.

In addition it looks like you post a new query for each value. you should create one query for all the data. and then just iterate of the results via the cursor. see: [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

And last one, I'd recommend you to load your data upon demand, as you get to the end of the list, a custom adapter will send a request to load more data. you could google for it.

Comment: can give me a link for the "load your data upon demand" trick

Comment: It's called `endless scrolling` or `infinite scroll`, just google it. here is something i found: https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

Comment: @Kirill.. in your second point you said not to make query in each iteration. But in my situation table1 have 2 fields id1 and id2 whose value is stored in table2 and table3. I have to get those value in the same hashmap... can this thing be done in only one query?? please

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Use AsyncTask instead of handler.
    //Like below :

    class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Adapter>{

          ProgressDialog progressDialog;
              protected void onPreExecute() {  
              progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,  

                    "", "Loading...", true);  
              super.onPreExecute();
        }  

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
       if (saudaList.size()==0) {
                getAllSaudaEntry();
             }
             Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
             msg.obj = saudaList;
             msg.sendToTarget();

         Vector<HashMap<String, String>> saudaList = (Vector<HashMap<String, String>>) msg.obj;
                        String[] from = {"date","sname","bname","contrno","item","quantity","rate"};
                        int[] to = {R.id.textViewSRdate,R.id.textViewSRSname,R.id.textViewSRBname,R.id.textViewSRcontrNo,R.id.textViewSRitem,R.id.textViewSRquantity,R.id.textViewSRrate};

      adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, saudaList,R.layout.sauda_row, from, to);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
                   progressDialog=null;
            return adapter;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             listView.setAdapter(result);
                       result.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

    }



   // call LoadData asynch class in onCreate function as below :

    new LoadData().execute();
```

Comment: @Neha... but I think it won't make any difference in time consumption.

Comment: AsyncTask make process fast .

Comment: @Neha AsyncTask makes the process "parallel", not faster.

Comment: Exaclty Vyger, and same thing I had achieved using java thread.

Comment: if you make process parallel then it makes execution time fast

Comment: @Neha-Systematix... as you can see in the code I had also made a new thread t and started it which runs parallely to the main thread(UI Thread).... but I will try the AsyncTask way.. thanks

Comment: @Neha: the overall execution is faster, but not the query "per se".